# How to get rid of this "100% Disk utilization across all physical drives in Windows 8.1" and "PC-hang"?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, freeze

[image: Disk utilization]

As you see in the above screenshot in my task manager in Win 8.1 the "Disk" utilization is 100%. In my pc it gets 100% repeatedly after few minutes interval. And when it happens my pc gets stuck. i can't even move the mouse pointer. This is the description of my problem. now my questions are...

1. What is actually this Disk, as far as I know this is my hard disk drive but still i want to know that is it only my Hard Disk Drive or something more, because i have enough free spaces in my hard disk but it still gets hang.
2. When The Disk utilization gets 100% and actually why?

And

3. What is/are the solution/solutions of my problem? Do i need to increase my PC's hardware capacity like do i need to increase the space capacity of my Hard Disk? or Something Else?

Note: Please pardon any kind of mistake in my question. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are updates downloading/installing in the background? Are they application running on the background/startup doing constant I/O operations? You may want to check this guide and check it out if this solves it: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-tips-fix-100-disk-usage-improve-windows-performance/

Comment: no downloading and installing in the background as far as i know... and i also checked the startup ... only few services are enabled which have medium and low impact.@CaldeiraG

Comment: okay let me check the guide @CaldeiraG

Comment: windows 10 builtin Resource Monitor tools should suffice here. All you need to do is get out what process has the highest Read/Write or Total value described here in "Disk Tab". Generally spoken using an SSD Harddrive should always solve/workaround these kind of troubles. But on a weak PC, you might get into CPU bottleneck then because the harddrive is too fast (e.g. on EEEPC and co)

Comment: Click on the cpu utilization header to sort processes using cpu, what process is using the most?

Comment: @CaldeiraG the [https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-tips-fix-100-disk-usage-improve-windows-performance/] guide works i think. It doesn't solve the frequent 100% disk utilization but My pc doesn't get stuck as much as before. Actually i am satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Their are many reasons of the full utilisation of your disk but the main reason for this is :

When a program is running in your system it continuesly need to contact the Hard drive of your computer for transferring the data b/w RAM and disk, as you hard drive speed is very slow as compared to your processor power or RAM speed that's why your disk is busy all the time, this is too the reason of opening the application slowly as it loads on RAM from disk with slower speed than RAM ....

Their is no connection b/w disk utilisation and space left in your Hard drive

The solutions of that is :

- You can try to defragment your hard drive
- Upgrade to SSD (best solution)